# Should repeated logic in Python code be moved into a decorator? Or is it better to keep them in the function's body?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I have a codebase with a lot of repeated logic - mainly around input validation. Eg.

```
def get_temperature(country:str, date:str|None=None)->float:
   date = pd.to_datetime(date).date() if date is not None else datetime.now().date()
   country = lookup_country_isocode(country)
   ...

def get_sunset_time(country:str, date:str|None=None)->float:
   date = pd.to_datetime(date).date() if date is not None else datetime.now().date()
   country = lookup_country_isocode(country)
   ...
def get_sunrise_time(country:str, date:str|None=None)->float:
   date = pd.to_datetime(date).date() if date is not None else datetime.now().date()
   country = lookup_country_isocode(country)
   ...
```

I'm thinking of refactoring the code by introducing a decorator:

```
def prepare_input(func):    
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['date'] = pd.to_datetime(date).date() if date is not None else datetime.now().date()
        kwargs['country'] = lookup_country_isocode(country)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner
```

This would let me write:

```
@prepare_input
def get_temperature(country:str, date:str|None=None)->float:
   ...

@prepare_input
def get_sunset_time(country:str, date:str|None=None)->float:
   ...

@prepare_input
def get_sunrise_time(country:str, date:str|None=None)->float:
   ...
```

However, I've not seen this done before, so keen to learn of any antipattern/code smell this might result in.

Comment: This would be better suited for [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) (or, with more code shown, perhaps [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: BTW, the "is not None" in "if date is not None" is probably redundant.

Comment: Probably not worth a full answer but I’d be tempted to use a Pydantic model to take in the arguments.  Ex:  `params = CountryQryParam(**locals())`.  Pydantic is pretty good at conversions, validations and explicit errors.  You’d need a custom validator for country but that’s easily done (and cached).

Answer (score 0):

this is going to get me downvoted since stack overflow generally does not like opinion based answers, but i would avoid `prepare_input` as that is not very explicit, and would likely confuse a user

I would recommend one of two methods if you would like to use a decorator... the first way is simply to be explicit, but even that is likely to confuse users

here is an example of being explicit

```
from dateutil.parser import parse as date_parse
import inspect

def args_to_kwargs(fn,args):
    print("GET ARGS:",inspect.getfullargspec(fn))
    data = dict(zip(inspect.getfullargspec(fn).args,args))
    return data

def alter_args(**alters):
    def __decorator(fn):
        def __inner(*args,**kwargs):
            # convert positional args to keyword args
            kwargs2 = {**args_to_kwargs(fn,args),**kwargs}
            for key in alters:
                if key in kwargs2:
                    #apply alteration
                    kwargs2[key] = alters[key](kwargs2[key])
            return fn(**kwargs2)
        return __inner
    return __decorator

iso_codes = {'us':'us_en','gb':'gb_en'}
@alter_args(date=date_parse,
            code=lambda c:iso_codes.get(c,c))
def test(date:str,code:str):
    print("GOT DATE:",date)
    print("GOT code:",code)

test('2021-01-22 13:45','us')
```

I would instead recommend a type based system (editing to provide it in a minute)

```
def enforce_types(fn):   
    annotations = inspect.getfullargspec(fn).annotations
    def __inner(*args,**kwargs):
        # convert positional args to keyword args
        kwargs2 = {**args_to_kwargs(fn, args), **kwargs}
        for key in annotations:
            if key in kwargs2:
                print('AAA:',annotations,kwargs2,key)
                # instanciate the Type
                klass = annotations[key]
                kwargs2[key] = klass(kwargs2[key])
        return fn(**kwargs2)
    print(annotations)
    return __inner

class MyDateTime:
    def __init__(self,datetimeString):
        # some hackery since its hard to actually subclass datetime
        self.dt = date_parse(datetimeString)
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.dt,item)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.dt)
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.dt)

class MyISOCode:
    iso_codes = {'us': 'us_en', 'gb': 'gb_en'}
    def __init__(self,code):
        self.code = code
        self.long =  self.iso_codes.get(code,code)
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.long, item)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.long
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.dt)

@enforce_types
def test(date:MyDateTime, iso_code:MyISOCode):
    print("Got Date:",repr(date))
    print("Got ISO:",iso_code)

test('2021-02-02 13:05','us')
```

but really why not just convert the date once early and pass that around instead of a string that you have to constantly convert?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here:

1. Refactor code: put repeating logic in a function.

   Consider writing a separate function `prepare_input` with just the repeating logic. Then,

   - either use [`pandas.DataFrame.Pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) functionality, to pipe the functions.
   - or, use the function to call from within each of the three functions if you prefer that way.
2. Using decorators:

   Decorators are very useful. However, if you have the logic in a simple function, it could be easier for maintainability. For easy implementation of decorators, you could also use the `decorators` library: https://pypi.org/project/decorator/.

There could be an additional benefit in using a function over a decorator: you could potentially integrate frameworks like Kedro for reproducible data-science.

### References

- [A Better Way for Data Preprocessing: Pandas Pipe](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-better-way-for-data-preprocessing-pandas-pipe-a08336a012bc)
- [Kedro — A Python Framework for Reproducible Data Science Project](https://towardsdatascience.com/kedro-a-python-framework-for-reproducible-data-science-project-4d44977d4f04)